# Average time by matching names

Tags: excel, vba

Find the average time `hh:mm` by finding the matching names in Column A(Workername) and using their times in Column M(Time Taken) and placing the average in Column N(Average Time Taken). Right now this is the code I have just to get time placed in Column M:

`With Worksheets("Raw Data")
  .Range("M2").Formula = "=FLOOR(K2-J2,1)&"":""&TEXT(K2-J2,""hh:mm"")"
  .Range("M2:M" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row).FillDown
End With`

I need to add coding to it so that I can get the average time.

Comment: have a look at the =AverageIfS function if you're using Excel2007 or greater.

Answer (score 0):

Add a header row to your data if not there yet. Select the whole data range. Insert a pivot table. Drop the name column as row header and the time as a value. Change the value to an average.

First, do that manually. When you actually get what you want, record a macro while redoing the exact same steps. Finally, modify the macro to remove harcoded row numbers.

Comment: How would I do that using VBA?